# Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate Custom TextField

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I am trying to receive textfield text and send it to another struct. But getting this error.
ALso when I try to call .onRecieve(Just(text)} data in... Xcode does not understand what Just is.

```
struct CardInfo : View {
@State var creditCard : CreditCard
@State var isSaved: Bool = false
@State private(set) var text = ""
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "Kartin Uzerindeki Isim", tFImage: "user")
            .textContentType(.givenName)
            .onReceive(text) { data in
                creditCard.cardOwnerName = text
        }
        CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "Kredi Kart Numarasi", tFImage: "credit")
            .textContentType(.oneTimeCode)
            .keyboardType(.numberPad)
        HStack {
            CreditCardDateTextField(tFtext: "", tFImage: "date")
                .textContentType(.creditCardNumber)
            Spacer()
            Text("")
                .overlay(
                    Rectangle()
                        .frame(width: 70, height: 53))
            Text("|")
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "CCV", tFImage: "")
                .textContentType(.creditCardNumber)
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9647058824, green: 0.9725490196, blue: 0.9882352941, alpha: 1)))
        Group {
            CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "Kart Ismi", tFImage: "cardEdit")
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.isSaved.toggle()
            }, label: { CustomButton(title: "Kaydet", icon: .none, status: .enable)
            })
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .padding()
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `.onReceive` on state, you need publisher, like `Just`, which is defined in defined in `Combine` framework, so you need to import it.

```
import Combine

...

        CustomTextField(data: $text, tFtext: "Kartin Uzerindeki Isim", tFImage: "user")
            .textContentType(.givenName)
            .onReceive(Just(text)) { data in
                creditCard.cardOwnerName = text
        }
```

Comment: It ended the error but when I add some texts on one of the textfield others are copying all the letters too.